# What do i need for an vertical aeroponic farm?

Tags: building-materials

I'm planning to make some money with the land I own (more than 60 hectares). I live in Brazil so water, sun and wind are readily available. I want to make an aeroponic vertical plantation inside a closed environment for optimal performance/quality/disease control.

I did some research on google and I know that I need an industrial vaporizer (among other things), but I still don't feel confident what I know and I can't make a list of all the things I need.

Let's assume I have $15000 dollars for the whole closed environment + the machinery and workers aren't a problem and I want to start small for testing proof of concept etc.

My aim is to sell organic food for a fair price and high quality and performance, if possible without spending too much (at least in the beginning – remember I'm doing it to gather capital).

What would be the best way to start this out? If possible a list of all items required to build a small environment.

I hope I was clear on my thoughts and also that some expert can help me.

Comment: I don't know if it would have an better forum to ask this but i thought  that this one would be a good place since aeroponics i really sustainable especially on small scales and is the one with less impact on environment and an guide like that could inspire many people to do the same maybe to business maybe to feed themselves

Comment: Pricing is outside the scope of this site; it's intended to provide useful lasting information, and pricing changes relatively quickly. However, the rest of the question seems well worded, so best of luck for getting a good answer, and welcome to the site! :-)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Sustainability.SX! I tried to revise your question for easier reading. Please undo any changes you feel are inappropriate (by clicking "edit").

Comment: I think the question about applying sustainability principles to your business is quite separate from your aeroponics project. Maybe it would be better to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Ok thanks guys i've edited the question the price i can search for myself

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are wasting your money.  If you already have 60 hectares, you have more land than you can develope with $15,000.

Anything vertical costs more money. You need more substantial frameworks.  You need ways to get materials to the upper levels.  Your employees spend more time on ladders and stools.

This additional spending can make sense in a northern community, as a vertical farm can take advantage of the low solar angle of winter, can be more efficient for heating, and can be built where land is expensive, and can be more productive per man hour where labour is expensive.

In Brazil, you have cheap land, abundant sun, cheap labour.  Farm the 60 hectares you have.

Comment: Yes but i feel i would make much more money with aeroponics won't I ? My productivity will be much more than traditional farming so much more money? I can do normal farming then go aeroponic later but i still want an closed environment for high productivity all year and disease control

Comment: @Freedom Have you visited organic farms (traditional farming) in Brazil? (As a matter of coincidence, friends of mine have an organic farm in Brazil.) Have you visited an aeroponic farm (anywhere)? That might give you some idea of what's possible...

Comment: @Earrhlin No i never visited any farm and wow thats nice maybe your friend can agree to share intel with me ?

Comment: No, I think you will make *far* more money with conventional farming.  The additional expenses of aeroponics only make sense with an unfavourable climate AND expensive land.